# How to pass arguments to .sql file from shell script

Tags: sql, bash, shell

Hi there if anyone can help me, I have a .sh script that executes 4 .sql scripts, each executing against a schema. Currently the schema name is hardcoded but i want to make it configurable.

Given the following below how will i pass the arguments from the shell script to the .files?

an e.g call to a .sql is done in my shell script is done so like the following

```
ECHO “DELETING SCHEME….”
psql -f $SCRIPT_DIR/delete_data.sql my_db postgres
ECHO “DATABASE SCHEMA DELETED..”
```

delete_data.sql

```
drop schema my_schema cascade;
create schema my_schema;
```

Comment: this is offtop, but php's `include` would solve this at once

Comment: unfortunately this has got nothing to do with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the `my_schema` part with a placeholder, like `%SCHEMA%`:

```
drop schema %SCHEMA% cascade;
create schema %SCHEMA%;
```

We then run a substitution using `sed`, and pipe the results into `psql` (reading from stdin is equivalent to reading from file):

```
sed "s/%SCHEMA%/$schemaName/" $SCRIPT_DIR/delete_data.sql | psql powa_aim_db postgres
```

Comment: Hi Carlpett. Something in the syntax is wrong. As a test, when i execute just the following in the command line    

    “s/%MY_SCHEMA%/$SCHEMA_NAME/“ delete_data.sql

it returns me the sql with the schema name substituted as desired. But when i run it as part of the whole statement as you have put in your answer i get the the error ending

   :0: could not read from input file: Is a directory

Comment: @L-Samuels: That's because I can't copy paste my own code, apparently >.< I'll edit in a correction.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a heredoc for your SQL:

```bash
my_schema="$1"
ECHO “DELETING SCHEME….”
psql <<SQL
drop schema $my_schema cascade
create schema $my_schema
SQL
ECHO “DATABASE SCHEMA DELETED..”
```

Then call your script with the schema name as the first argument:

```
$ ./my_script my_schema_name
```